# Get file content from .tar.gz from AWS S3. TypeScript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tar

I have a problem with getting content's file from .tar.gz from s3 bucket.
I have s3 bucket with .tar.gz. My archive contains only one text file. I want to get content from this file in memory. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a storage service, it cannot process data or do anything other than store data (well, it can move it to but that is not the case here).
For that you'd need a lambda function (or something similar to process your file)

If you'd go with a lambda function (which is my recommendation) you can look at this
[unzip and add to bucket here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226804/aws-lambda-how-to-extract-a-tgz-file-in-a-s3-bucket-and-put-it-in-another-s3-bu)