# Read a tar.gz compressed file form a file stream, uncompress it and put it in another file stream without writing to disk

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, tar

I have a big 1GB directory with multiple files that is stored in S3 in the format tar.gz and manipulated by a Lambda function.

The file system of the Lambda function is read only. So I would like the operations to be done in memory.

I cannot include it in the image of the Lambda function itself, as GitHub won't accept such large files.

Having Lambda to read it from S3 seems to be reasonable but I can't get how to uncompress it. Sorry, I'm a beginner.

Here is what I wrote:

```py
# Define the resources to use
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
bucket = s3.Bucket('tensorflow-models')
object = bucket.Object('saved-model.tar.gz')

# Prepare 2 file streams
file_stream1 = io.BytesIO()
file_stream2 = io.BytesIO()

# Download object to file stream
object.download_fileobj(file_stream1)

# Uncompress it
with tarfile.open(file_stream1, "r:gz") as tar:
    tar.extractall(file_stream2)

# Use it in Tensorflow
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(file_stream2)

# Get the result
result = model.call(embedded_sentences)
```

Here is the error message:

```s
{
  "errorMessage": "expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
  "requestId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/app.py\", line 87, in lambda_handler\n    with tarfile.open(file_stream1, \"r:gz\") as tar:\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/tarfile.py\", line 1629, in open\n    return func(name, filemode, fileobj, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/tarfile.py\", line 1675, in gzopen\n    fileobj = GzipFile(name, mode + \"b\", compresslevel, fileobj)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.9/gzip.py\", line 173, in __init__\n    fileobj = self.myfileobj = builtins.open(filename, mode or 'rb')\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can work with **1Gb file** from your lambda, because there is a **512 MB** in its temp directory limitation (please check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)

Please check for large file, mount an EFS to the lambda or change to logic (explore another possibility worker  instead of lambda)

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is using the RAM memory of the lambda, instead of using the ephemeral storage. Refer to the Python answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226804/aws-lambda-how-to-extract-a-tgz-file-in-a-s3-bucket-and-put-it-in-another-s3-bu).

Basically, you will be unzipping file by file inside the zip and loading each one of them at a time into memory instead of doing everything at once. The code snippet from the source link can be found in here with a single thread solution:

```py
import boto3
import botocore
import tarfile

from io import BytesIO
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def untar_s3_file(event, context):

    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    input_tar_file = s3_client.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
    input_tar_content = input_tar_file['Body'].read()

    with tarfile.open(fileobj = BytesIO(input_tar_content)) as tar:
        for tar_resource in tar:
            if (tar_resource.isfile()):
                inner_file_bytes = tar.extractfile(tar_resource).read()
                s3_client.upload_fileobj(BytesIO(inner_file_bytes), Bucket = bucket, Key = tar_resource.name)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33079390)

Comment: I updated the answer with the same sample code provided in the correspondent link, thanks for the feedback. The code is pretty straightforward although it was not written by me.